# What is the equivilent for "Cmd + Space" on Mac for Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mac

Is there any shortcut to open search bar for applications like "Cmd + Space"(on Mac) for Linux.
I searched for that but couldn't find anything for now

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 (Bionic Beaver)
and also Linux Mint 18 "Sarah" - Cinnamon for another computer

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post and explain in details the exact feature you're looking for? On Ubuntu 18.04.1, doesn't pressing <super> and typing keywords work?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 both use <kbd>Super</kbd>, which you may be more familiar with being called the "Command" or "Windows" key.

If you're using Kubuntu you can pres <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) launcher for GNU/Linux is the closest equivalent to the Cmd+Space (Spotlight) functionality on macOS in terms of appearance, usage, and functionality.

Tips to get up and running:

- Install synapse with `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install synapse`.
- Synapse can be configured to search programs, directories, files, do math, etc.  These are the "plugins" that can be toggled from the Settings of Synapse.
- Set Cmd+Space (or Alt+Space) launch key as the "Activate" shortcut in the Settings of Synapse.
- Set "Startup at login" in the Settings of Synapse. (The "Show notification icon" option is obviously up to you, but it can be nice to have, to see that Synapse is running.)

Comments:

- Having tried other launchers to fit this need, I find Synapse very much to be the closest to replicating the Spotlight experience on Mac.
- The Zeitgeist indexer that Spotlight uses for file indexing by default seems pretty smart and lightweight.  While using Zeitgeist is optional, this fulfills some aspects of what the Mac Spotlight search does (knowing what recent or commonly used files are and more).